# I don't see the new line using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have this code using HTML

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="12" id="hour"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to use javascript like this :

```
$('#hour').empty();
$('#hour').text(begin+ " \n "+end);
```

The problem is that I have no a new line for the variable end...

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Use <br> tag instead of \n

Comment: The answers describe how to fix this, but to clarify why this isn't working - well, actually, it is. It does output a newline. The problem is that you're outputting HTML, and HTML treats any amount of whitespace as equivalent to just a single space. So the fact that there's a newline character there makes no difference to the output you see in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are adding that context in a HTML page inside a `<div>`, suggested way is to use `html()` function instead of `text()`. Then, you can use `<br/>` to add a new line. So, when this entire content is rendered as a HTML, then `<br/>` will add a new line. This also defines the difference between `text()` and `html()` function.

```js
var begin = 'begin';
var end = 'end';
$('#hour').empty();
$('#hour').html(begin + "<br/> " + end);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
  <div class="12" id="hour"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `html()` instead of `text()` and `<br>` instead of `\n`

```js
$('#hour').empty();
$('#hour').html('begin'+ "<br>"+'end');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc">
    <div class="12" id="hour"></div>
</div>
```